# WiFi range problems

Tags: wireless-networking, minipci

I changed a miniPCI WiFi card in my old Compaq TC1000 tablet PC to Intel 2100BG (the original one supported only the B standard). It worked quite well for two months. Then I opened the tablet to clean it, and after reassembling the card lost its range. Now it works only in the room where the wifi router is (with status indicator signalling very weak signal), and it used to work in my whole flat without any problems.

I temporarily put another BG card and the wireless went back to good range... so I am guessing the problem is in the WiFi card.

Is there anything I can do to fix the card? I could order a replacement card, but in a place where I live this will take some time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't also changed drivers for the card at the time that you cleaned the tablet, then I suppose that you have proven that the card has gone bad.

You should really next time pay attention to [Safety Precautions when Fixing or Assembling a Computer](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/1676152/safety_precautions_when_fixing_or_assembling.html).